# How to get integer value from Sqlite Database?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, sqlite

I am working with Sqlite Database.

In my database

I have some filed Like, Invoice,Name,Date

My Invoiceno datatype is INTEGER,

In Select query  Got output like this.

```
 Query:(
    {
     InvoiceNo = 1;
     Name : ABC
     Date = "2012-04-16 00:00:00";

    }
  )
```

But when try to Get that Invoice no to string it's given Diff. Value.

Code for getting invoice from array to String:

```
  NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[[Query objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"InvoiceNo"]];
    NSLog(@"str:%@",str);
```

Here, My invoice no is 1, & It's give me a value "2387056"

Please, Help me..How can i solve this problem?

Comment: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[Query objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"InvoiceNo"]]; maybe it will help you.

Comment: %d and %i should result with a 32bit int

Comment: @chinttu Thanks for Answer,it's given me other string value...

Comment: @Anki you have to do %d or doin typecast "intValue" .. maybe it will help. u got answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[[Query objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"InvoiceNo"]];
    NSLog(@"str:%@",str);
you have to replace above lines with below lines

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[[[Query objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"InvoiceNo"] intValue]];
    NSLog(@"str:%@",str);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Convert NSString to int](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=convert%20NSString%20to%20int&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&safe=on)

```
NSString *values = @"1";

int yourValue = [values intValue];

NSLog(@"Int Value : %d",yourValue);
```